# How to disable Sitefinity Post blog Single Item

Tags: widget, blogs, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

My website has in the footer the last 5 post summaries of my blog.

The problem:

When I am reading a post, my footer is showing the same post instead of showing the summary.

I want to disable a Single Item from the footer. Is it possible to do that or Do I have to create a widget just for my footer?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plese check this blog post for the answer:

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/slavo-ingilizovs-blog/2011/12/15/url_filtering_with_multiple_content_widgets_per_page

Hope this solves your problem.

Ivan

Comment: thank you very much. I have been trying to do this for 1 week and I have given up already.
You are the best!